# Accessing a specific instance of a component (edited)

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm trying to access a specific instance of a component where the app uses it several times in other components. When I use the query command "fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ComponentName)).componentInstance;", it will only pick up on the first created instance of ComponentName.

I've broken down the example into this basic version:

random.test.component.html

```
<random-test-child>
</random-test-child>

<snack-time
    [bestSnack]="cheeseAndCrackers">
</snack-time>
```

random.test.component.child.html

```
<snack-time
    [bestSnack]="applesAndOranges">
</snack-time>

<snack-time
    [bestSnack]="cookies">
</snack-time>
```

*all variable names are strings in their respective .ts files (e.g., applesAndOranges is "Apples and Oranges")

The component selected by the query command has "Apples and Oranges" as the value of bestSnack. If I wanted to specifically access "Cookies" or "Cheese and Crackers", is there a way to do that (aside from adding an id tag)?

EDIT

Okay, different plan: I'm using fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(SnackTime)).componentInstance in the spec file to pick out the SnackTime elements. I've added in another SnackTime to the original random.test.component.html so it now reads as follows:

```
<snack-time
    [bestSnack]="cheeseAndCrackers">
</snack-time>

<snack-time
    [bestSnack]="chipsAndSoda">
</snack-time>
```

The idea I have in mind is to create a QueryList or array of the SnackTime elements and pick out the specific instance from there. However, if I do so as follows:

let componentsInThePage:SnackTime[] = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(SnackTime)).componentInstance;

I get an array that only has the first created SnackTime component rather than the two from the random.test.component.html file (the two in the child.html file don't appear either). How do I create a list/array of the SnackTime components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to my edit.

The key is to use "queryAll" instead of "query", then turn all DebugElements into instances of SnackTime. This will result in an array of all SnackTime elements, including those in other html files.

```
    let debugComponentsInThePage:DebugElement[] = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(SnackTime));
    let componentsInThePage:SnackTime[] = [];

    for(var i=0; i<debugComponentsInThePage.length; i++){
        componentsInThePage[i] = debugComponentsInThePage[i].componentInstance;
        console.log(componentsInThePage[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template reference variable

If you wanted to operate on that component instance inside of the model.ts file you could use the @ViewChild decorator like `@ViewChild('cookies') cookies: SnackTimeComponent`to grab a reference to it.

Or you could just use it somewhere else in the template.
`<div>I have {{cookies.numCookies}} cookies!</div>`

(assuming the property numCookies exists on the SnackTimeComponent class)

Comment: if use `@ViewChildren(SnackTimeComponent) snaks:QueryList<SnackTimeComponent>`, you has all the snak-time. A `this.snaks.find(x=>x.bestSnack=='Cookies')` get you the snak with cookies. See the docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Comment: What about in a spec file? I'm doing unit testing, and I can't seem to access the component outside of the original .ts file.

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-unit-testing-viewchild-4525e0c7b756

Comment: I've solved the problem in a different way, but thank you for your help!